# androidでPDF読み込むアプリを作りたいがエラーになる

Tags: java, android, pdf

androidで他のアプリからPDFを読み込んでPDFを表示させたいのですが上手く表示できませんでした。
何も描写されません。
原因のわかる方教えていただけませんか。

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        //String name=uri.getLastPathSegment();
        String path =uri.getPath();

        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = null;
        PdfRenderer renderer = null;
        PdfRenderer.Page page = null;
        try {
            // SDカード直下からtest.pdfを読み込み、1ページ目を取得
            fd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(path), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
            renderer = new PdfRenderer(fd);
            page = renderer.openPage(1);

            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
            float pdfWidth = page.getWidth();
            float pdfHeight = page.getHeight();
            Log.i("test", "viewWidth=" + viewWidth + ", viewHeight=" + viewHeight
                    + ", pdfWidth=" + pdfWidth + ", pdfHeight=" + pdfHeight);

            // 縦横比合うように計算
            float wRatio = viewWidth / pdfWidth;
            float hRatio = viewHeight / pdfHeight;
            if (wRatio <= hRatio) {
                viewHeight = (int) Math.ceil(pdfHeight * wRatio);
            } else {
                viewWidth = (int) Math.ceil(pdfWidth * hRatio);
            }
            Log.i("test", "drawWidth=" + viewWidth + ", drawHeight=" + viewHeight);

            // Bitmap生成して描画
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            page.render(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight), null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fd != null) {
                    fd.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (page != null) {
                page.close();
            }
            if (renderer != null) {
                renderer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーは出ていませんか？端末のバージョンが6.0以上であれば、ストレージのパーミッションの取得が必要です。

Comment: ストレージのパーミッションの取得で
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
を追記しましたがPDFが表示されません。
URIの中が空かと思い調べましたが
 pathには/storage/emulated/0/test.pdfが入ってました。
その他、原因になりそうなことはありませんか？

Comment: マニフェストに宣言するのは、`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`だけで良いです。Android6.0以降では、マニフェストとは別に、実行時に[ランタイムパーミッション](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)も取得しなければいけません。